# Как вывести последнее значение по времени SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Есть таблица

```
id  Date_time   Log
1   01.10.2021 15:30    Действие 1
1   01.10.2021 15:35    Действие 2
2   02.10.2021 10:00    Действие 1
2   02.10.2021 12:00    Действие 2
```

Необходимо получить по каждому id последний лог, то есть на выходе должно получиться:

```
id  Date_time   Log
1   01.10.2021 15:35    Действие 2
2   02.10.2021 12:00    Действие 2
```

Залил [данные](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/16a42/1) :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь CTE и оконной функцией [row_number()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
with tab as (
   select 
      id, Date_time, Log, 
      row_number() over(partition by id order by Date_time desc) as rn
   from table_name
)
select 
    id, Date_time, Log 
from tab 
where rn = 1
```

[SQL-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c7836/1)

Comment: Так, я честно не знаю, как ответить на этот вопрос. Создаю БД на http://sqlfiddle.com, MS SQL Server 2017. Об этом речь?

Comment: @CR7, вы для какой БД планируете это использовать? PS и fiddle, соответственно лучше создавать для того типа БД, который вы будете использовать

Comment: планирую для QSL Server

Comment: @CR7, добавил метку в вопрос... Кстати, было бы неплохо привести в вопросе ссылку на SQLFiddle с примером таблицы - тогда отвечающие на ваш вопрос люди смогли бы протестировать свои ответы )

Comment: пробую на сайте, почему то не получается, пишет ошибку ```Invalid object name 'table_name'.```

Comment: @CR7, добавил ссылку на SQL-fiddle в ответ